# sub queries order by

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying get records from question order by sub query (qcat) table. and my code is

```
"SELECT *  FROM question
where survey_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]' AND
      qcategory IN
         ( SELECT qcategory FROM qcat
           WHERE client_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]'
           GROUP BY qcategory
           ORDER BY p_order
         ) AND 
      status='1' AND
      survey_name LIKE'%$sname%
LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

But it did not get results in order.

how can i get rows order by the qcat table?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what all of the columns are in each of the two tables.

Comment: There are no aggregating functions in this query so GROUP BY is inappropriate. Name the columns you actually want returned, and see JOIN and SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to join with the `qcat` table in order to be able to sort on a different column within that table. Try this:

```
$query = "
  SELECT q.id question_id, q.*, c.*
  FROM question q
  INNER JOIN qcat c ON c.category = q.category
  WHERE q.survey_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]'
    AND c.client_name = '$_SESSION[ssn_sname]'
    AND q.status='1'
    AND q.survey_name like '%$sname%'
  GROUP BY q.id
  ORDER BY c.p_order
  LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

**Note:** Your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: how to protect my query to SQL Injectio?

Comment: If you are not using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or some API that sanitizes query arguments for you, be sure to run [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on any arguments to your query before running the query. For example, you should only pass `$_SESSION[ssn_sname]` to your query string after it has been run through `mysqli_real_escape_string` like this: `$_SESSION[ssn_sname] = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION[ssn_sname]);`

Comment: order is solved but when i tried to get question id like $row[id] it fetch qcat table's qcategory id instead of question id. how should i call the question id?

Comment: @ukdub - What are all of the columns in the `question` table? Is there a primary key?

Comment: yes in question table id is the primary and auto increment key. i made the category as field's order is changeable and want to get question order with category's p_order values

Comment: @ukdub - Have you tried changing the bottom `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY q.id`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your initial question. See my revised answer. I updated the `SELECT` clause. You may want to pull in only the fields that you need to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the sub query you do not need the `GROUP BY` clause - This is used for aggregated functions
2. You also do not need the `ORDER BY` in the sub query - Let mysql work it out for the `in` bit
3. Add the `ORDER BY` for the whole query. i.e. at the end

So the SQL should be

```
"SELECT *  FROM question
where survey_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]' AND
      qcategory IN
         ( SELECT qcategory FROM qcat
           WHERE client_name='$_SESSION[ssn_sname]'              
         ) AND 
      status='1' AND
      survey_name LIKE'%$sname%
ORDER BY p_order
LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

I also think that you may be able to avoid the sub query in the first place. But that would require a little thinking and a bit more knowledge about the tables.

BTW - Note the possibility of SQL injection